# How to import a text log file into a excel columns

Tags: excel, text

I have some data of form

```
[39645961,-79966658]358920045121212[0.75]2013-01-30 20:47:52
[39646124,-79966771]358920045121212[0.5]2013-01-30 20:47:54
[39646134,-79966733]358920045121212[0.5]2013-01-30 20:47:56
[39646123,-79966723]358920045121212[0.5]2013-01-30 20:47:58
[39646144,-79966724]358920045121212[0.5]2013-01-30 20:48:09
......
```

How can I import them into an excel file into separate columns. like

```
39645961 -79966658 358920045121212 0.75 2013-01-30 20:47:52
39646124 -79966771 358920045121212 0.5 2013-01-30 20:47:54
39646134 -79966733 358920045121212 0.5 2013-01-30 20:47:5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Write a macro using VBA that reads the data, separates the columns, and inserts data in appropriate cells.

Comment: Will all the data elements other than the 0.75 column always be the same length?

Comment: You could use a text editor and replace '[', ',', and ']' with ' ' (a single space) and save it as a text file. Then in Excel go to Data -> From Text, select your text file, select "Delimited", press Next, then click the checkbox next to "Space" for the delimiter, press Finish, and then press OK.

Comment: Yes all the fields except 0.75 will be of same length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not too frequent task:

1. Copy-paste the text to Excel (will occupy one column)
2. Data - Text to Columns (Excel 2003)
3. Delimiters: Comma and Other: `]`
4. After completing the operations, insert a column after the remaining non-splitted fragment (`358920045121212[0.75`) and repeat Text to Columns for this column only with Other delimiter as `[`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Copy the data into a text file, like Notepad.

2) Use find and replace to replace bracket characters with a tab character.
You can not directly type a tab character into the replace field, because it will just     move your cursor to the next field. To get around this:
Open another Notepad window and press tab, then copy the tab into the replace field of the original Notepad window. Hit replace and repeat this process with space and comma characters.

3) Save and close the notepad file.

4) Open the notepad file in Excel. (choose file, open, and don't forget to change the file type in the open dialog from "All Excel Files" to "All Files"

5) This will open the Text Import Wizard. Hit next, next and finished, and the data should show up in separate columns

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it strictly in Excel, you will have to extract the individual data elements from each string using a combination of text functions, including SEARCH or FIND, LEFT, MID and RIGHT. The following formulas show one wqy to extract each element from one of the strings, which I have assumed is in A1.

```
  =MID(A1,2,SEARCH(",",A1)-2)
  =MID(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)+1,SEARCH("]",A1)-SEARCH(",",A1)-1)
  =MID(A1,SEARCH("]",A1)+1,SEARCH("]",A1)+SEARCH("[",MID(A1,SEARCH("]",A1),99))-SEARCH("]",A1)-2)
  =MID(A1,SEARCH("[",A1,2)+1,SEARCH("]",MID(A1,SEARCH("[",A1,2)+1,99))-1)
  =MID(A1,SEARCH("????-??-??",A1),10)
  =RIGHT(A1,8)
```

You would enter these formulas horizontally to the right of A1, then copy them down.

Comment: The data should be fit in multiple columns and rows

Comment: I think I understand. The idea would be to enter the first formula in a cell to the right of A1, say C1. Then the 2nd formula would go into cell D1, the 3rd in E1, etc., through cell H1 The six formulas would break out the data string in A1 across 6 columns. Then you would copy the six formulas in C1:H1 downward. So if you have 100 strings in cells A1:A100 that you want to break apart, you would copy the formulas in C1:H1 down to fill the cells through C10)0:H100.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way - use a third party piece of software.

The one I used costs me very little for the year, but means i don't need to mess around with trying to get it right.

Its the only tool i found which isn't a monthly subscription as well.

Its a desktop based application.

https://onpage.rocks/product/server-log-tool/